# Set of density matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

A density matrix is a matrix $\rho \in \mathscr{D}:=\{A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}; A^*=A; \operatorname{tr}(A)=1; A \ge 0\}.$

In Quantum Mechanics it is natural to look at a group action

$\Phi: U(n) \times \mathscr{D} \rightarrow \mathscr{D}, (U,\rho) \mapsto U\rho U^*.$

Now, my quetion is: What is the kind of nicest structure that $\mathscr{D}$ can have and why?

First, I observed that $\mathscr{D}$ without the positivity condition is just something like a affine space, but $\mathscr{D}$ does not seem to be something like a manifold, as $\rho \ge 0$ apparently kind of destroys it.

So is there any interesting structure that $\mathscr{D}$ naturally posesses?

I am curious about the answers

Comment: The interior, where $A>0$, is a manifold, since positive definiteness is an open condition. If you want to talk about the boundary as well, it is a spectrahedron https://math.berkeley.edu/~bernd/WhatIsSpec.pdf .

Comment: It the intersection (let's call it slice) of the convex cone of positive semidefinite matrices with a hyperplane; the open part of the PSD cone may also be viewed as a nice Riemannian manifold. (seems like I was typing my comment while David was also typing...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a symmetric space when equipped by the metric discussed in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/115192/power-log-distance-between-matrices/115227#115227) (it is Riemannian, when $p=2$). The metric is clearly invariant under the action; its other properties can be checked (see the references in Suvrit's nice answer to the linked question, or see one of the papers by Freitas and Friedland, e.g. MR2014882 (2004j:30086) Reviewed 
Friedland, Shmuel(1-ILCC-MS); Freitas, Pedro J.(P-LISBS)
Revisiting the Siegel upper half plane. I. (English summary) 
Linear Algebra Appl. 376 (2004), 19–44.  )